# Different users can see, items added to the shopping cart , how do I avoid that

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am creating a shopping  cart ,  when a user click on add to cart the item name and price are added to firebase database, and  I will get the data from firebase  to the shopping cart page.  But the problem  I am facing is that,  if user (A) that  is logged into to the  app,  add an item to the shopping  cart list, user (B)  with a different  families will be able  to see it if he/she goes to the shopping  cart page.  Pls how to I avoid  that,  how do I make different  users with different  gmail/email   unable  to view an item added to the  list by another  user.    Thanks in advance

Comment: Without knowing your data schema this question is unanswerable.  But it sounds like you've developed a single user schema when you need a multi-user schema.  Which means you need to stop all development, and figure out what data should be visible to what users and make sure that the correct queries/server side filtering is in place everywhere.  This isn't a small problem, it means everything you've done is flawed.

Comment: your table structure should be bit different now i guess you are storing the card item no. in common space where you put anything is visible to others when you query. just separate the concerns like just relate the cart items with users id so different users can have different cart with their own ids.